# How do I prevent Windows 10 from signing in multiple accounts automatically at the same time?

Tags: windows-10

When I sign into my account on Windows 10.0.17763 Build 17763, my sister's account is also signed in automatically, and processes from her account are running in the background.

Comment: Is the account automatically logged into and you have switch user or something?

Comment: @Ramhound The account is automatically logged in.

Answer (score 0):

This is solved by restarting the computer. Only one account becomes logged in this way.